# Confidence and prediciton intervals for power law fit

Tags: confidence-interval, prediction-interval, uncertainty, error-propagation, power-law

I would like to determine confidence intervals and prediction intervals for a noisy dataset that follows a power law distribution.

I have a dataset that (to my eye) follows power law behavior in the form of *y = a x^b*. The measurements are noisy in both x and y, so I think an orthogonal distance regression is appropriate. The errors in both x and y appear to be normally distributed, as opposed to log-normally or similar. I have therefore modeled the dataset in Python as follows:

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import odr


# Dataset parameters
N = 1000

x_min = 8
x_max = 104
x_noise = 0.5

a = 0.1
b = 0.2
y_noise = 0.01


# Define power law function
def powerlaw(beta, x):
    """Power law model y = a x^b.
    """
    return beta[0] * x**beta[1]


# Generate dataset
x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, N)
y = powerlaw([a, b], x)

# Add noise
x += np.random.normal(0, x_noise, N)
y += np.random.normal(0, y_noise, N)


# ODR
powerlaw_model = odr.Model(powerlaw)
data = odr.Data(x, y)
model = odr.ODR(data, powerlaw_model, beta0=[0.1, 0.2])
output = model.run()
output.pprint()


# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, s=5, c='k')
ax.plot(x, powerlaw(output.beta, x), 'b')


plt.show()
```

The following plot is generated:
[image: Example powerlaw fit]

And the built-in scipy odr `pprint` function produces the following outputs:

```
Beta: [0.10018594 0.1995153 ]
Beta Std Error: [0.00104146 0.00257196]
Beta Covariance: [[ 0.0106286  -0.02598979]
 [-0.02598979  0.06482197]]
Residual Variance: 0.00010204824772858142
Inverse Condition #: 0.042024958083484526
```

My question is: From the ODR model outputs, how do I report a confidence interval for the fit parameters (e.g., *a* +/- *alpha_a* and *b* +/- *alpha_b*); and from those, how do I calculate a prediction interval for the data (i.e., *(a +- alpha_a) x^(b +- alpha_b) = y +- alpha_y)*?